# ggplot2: Coloring based on group in geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

Thank you for the responses! I have tried to clarify what I the output to be.

I have a dataset, d, like this read from a file.

```
   pass site value region
1     0    1     1      A
2     0    2    10      A
3     0    3    10      A
4     0    4    10      B
5     0    5    10      B
6     0    6    10      C
7     0    7    10      C
8     0    8    10      C
9     0    9    10      D
10    0   10    10      E
11    0   11     0      E
12    1    1   100      A
13    1    2    25      A
14    1    3    34      A
15    1    4    54      B
16    1    5    64      B
17    1    6    98      C
18    1    7    59      C
19    1    8    92      C
20    1    9    37      D
21    1   10    96      E
22    1   11    20      E
23    2    1    93      A
24    2    2    80      A
25    2    3     3      A
26    2    4    86      B
27    2    5    10      B
28    2    6    81      C
29    2    7     7      C
30    2    8    60      C
31    2    9    90      D
32    2   10     0      E
33    2   11   200      E
```

I'm mapping the proportion of each site in each pass based on the sites value in that passage. I want the sites to be colored by there region value. I have gotten it to color by region, but I want each site in the region to be one of three color I choose. These data set will be thousands of sites long, so I need to to cycle through each of the three colors. I have attached some examples of what I have done.

The example does give me the plot, but uses the default colors.

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=rev(pass),y=rev(value),group=site)) + 
  geom_area(aes(fill=factor(rev(r_var))), position = "Fill")
```

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT9iT.jpg)

The next example only cycles through the first option of colors for region A (all shades of grey/black), rather than going to the next region colors.

```
r_var<-d$region
number = 3000
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=rev(pass),y=rev(value),group=site)) + 
  geom_area(aes(fill=factor(rev(r_var))), position = "Fill") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(rep(c("#000000", "#151111", "#131111"),length.out = number),
                               rep(c("#231652", "#0e72ef", "#2c46c9"),length.out = number),
                               rep(c("#808080", "#a39f9f", "#514e4e"),length.out = number),
                               rep(c("#a50000", "#ff0000", "#e10000"),length.out = number),
                               rep(c("#56e729", "#b6ff15", "#6aff0c"),length.out = number)))
```

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YWGr.jpg)

The last example outputs a graph with no data.

```
r_var<-d$region
number = 3000
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=rev(pass),y=rev(value),group=site)) + 
  geom_area(aes(fill=factor(rev(r_var))), position = "Fill") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" =rep(c("#000000", "#151111", "#131111"),length.out = number),
                               "B" = rep(c("#231652", "#0e72ef", "#2c46c9"),length.out = number),
                               "C" = rep(c("#808080", "#a39f9f", "#514e4e"),length.out = number),
                               "D" = rep(c("#a50000", "#ff0000", "#e10000"),length.out = number),
                               "E" = rep(c("#56e729", "#b6ff15", "#6aff0c"),length.out = number)))
```

Comment: I'm not sure, I understand. The lines with `t = 2` and `t = 3` have the same region (`A`), but they should not be identically coloured? If this is indeed your intent, then how should ggplot decided which colour to use? Randomly or some regular scheme?

Comment: Also be more careful with your code. It won't work for the data you provided. For instance, there are no columns `val` and `var` in `d`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have clarified what I need my code to do and attached working examples.

Comment: number is just the max number of times I want to to repeat through the color set. I don't know how to set it the number of sites in each region.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I got this code to work with my data frame d:

```
small_d<-subset(d, pass == 0)
count_d<-aggregate(data.frame(count = small_d$region), list(value = small_d$region), length)

color.codes = c(rep(c("#000000", "#151111", "#131111"),length.out = count_d[1,2]),
                rep(c("#231652", "#2c46c9","#000099"),length.out = count_d[2,2]),
                rep(c("#404040", "#808080", "#514e4e"),length.out = count_d[3,2]),
                rep(c("#a50000", "#F505F5", "#ff0000"),length.out = count_d[4,2]),
                rep(c("#56e729", "#b6ff15", "#2FB531"),length.out = count_d[5,2]),
                rep(c("#909090", "#C8C8C8", "#B0B0B0"),length.out = count_d[6,2]),
                rep(c("#ff9900","#ffff00","#cc9900"),length.out = count_d[7,2]),
                rep(c("#00ffff","#99ffff","#00ccff"),length.out = count_d[8,2]),
                rep(c("#000000", "#151111", "#131111"),length.out = count_d[9,2]))

 ggplot(data=d,aes(rev(pass),rev(value),fill=rev(factor(interaction(region,site))),group=site))+
      geom_area(position="Fill")+
      scale_fill_manual(values = color.codes)
```